# How to use currentUser from NextJs in multiple components

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, fetch, next-auth

I have an app that uses NextAuth. I don't know if was the right thing to do, but I created a context to store the current user, and I want to use it in multiple components.

The problem is when the page loads and the user is logged out I get the following error in the console:

```
UserContext.js:21 GET http://localhost:3000/api/currentUser 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

```
"use client";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  console.log("current", currentUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCurrentUser = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/currentUser`);
        if (response.ok) {
          const userData = await response.json();
          setCurrentUser(userData);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching current user:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchCurrentUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={currentUser}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCurrentUser = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

This is currentUser route handler

```
import db from "@/prisma/db";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { authOptions } from "../auth/[...nextauth]/route";

export async function GET() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  const currentUser = await db.utilizatori.findFirst({
    where: {
      email: session.user.email,
    },
  });
  return NextResponse.json(currentUser);
}
```

How to make it to fetch the user only when the session is not null or should I take other approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should return a 401 if the session is invalid.

```
export async function GET() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  if (!session) { 
    res.status(401).json({ message: "You must be logged in." });
    return;
  }

  // rest of your code...
}
```

From the [NextAuth docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs)